# Die in the game, die in real life

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

I am looking for some help identifying a short film that I watched a couple years back. I have tried to track it down, but have been unsuccessful.

I remember watching a short film about some kids/teens that order VR goggles online for free. I think they arrive almost instantly, and they begin playing. The game was in a death match style and all players have creepy outfits with masks so that no one is recognisable. In the end of the story you find out that death in the game results in death in real life and that you are unable to take the goggles off. I recall a mother coming into one of the players room and finding their son dead (or seizuring) on his bed.

I thought it was a Black Mirror episode, but I was wrong.  So now I am thinking I watched it on Youtube.

Does anyone know what this is?

Note: the concept is similar to Sword Art Online, but thats not what im thinking of. It wasnt animated.

Comment: "Real VR death" is a fairly common trope. Can you remember *anything* else?

Comment: @Möoz I agree, it is quite common, and only becoming more so. This was part of the reason i couldnt find the specific story that i am remembering. Unfortunately i cant recall anymore.

Comment: That's all good. You might want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some searching, a friend of mine found the video. You can watch it below.